# Помогите с платным отключением рекламы в приложении

Tags: java, android

Помогите с платным отключением рекламы в приложении!

Есть класс в котором лежит сама реклама:

```
public class Commercial extends Activity {

    public Commercial(Activity activity) {}

    public void ad() {

    AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("");
    AdBuddiz.cacheAds(this); // this = current Activity
    AdBuddiz.showAd(this);

    }
```

и есть фрагмент в котором я все это дело объявляю:

```
// id вашей покупки из админки в Google Play
    static final String SKU_ADS_DISABLE = "com.ads.disable";
    // public key из админки Google Play
    public static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "";
    public final static String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TAG2 = "activities";
    static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
    IabHelper mHelper;
    private Context context;
    Commercial ads;

    public static SettingsFragment newInstance() {
        return new SettingsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.divider));
        return view;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        // грузим настройки
        PreferencesHelper.loadSettings(getActivity());

    Preference button2 = (Preference) findPreference("false_commercial");
    button2.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            if (!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled())
                buy();
            return true;
        }
    });

// инициализация билинга
billingInit();
// если отключили рекламу, то не будем показывать
ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());
}

private void buy() {
        if (!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled()) {
            /*
             * для безопасности сгенерьте payload для верификации. В данном
             * примере просто пустая строка юзается. Но в реальном приложение
             * подходить к этому шагу с умом.
             */
            String payload = "";
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), SKU_ADS_DISABLE, RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
        }
    }
    private void billingInit() {
        mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);

        // включаем дебагинг (в релизной версии ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО выставьте в false)
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

        // инициализируем; запрос асинхронен
        // будет вызван, когда инициализация завершится
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // чекаем уже купленное
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                }
            });
    }

    // Слушатель для востановителя покупок.
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        private static final String TAG = "QueryInventoryFinishedListener";

        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                LOG.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            LOG.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

            /*
             * Проверяются покупки. Обратите внимание, что надо проверить каждую
             * покупку, чтобы убедиться, что всё норм! см.
             * verifyDeveloperPayload().
             */

            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ADS_DISABLE);
            PreferencesHelper.savePurchase(context,
                                           PreferencesHelper.Purchase.DISABLE_ADS, purchase != null
                                           && verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase));
            ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            LOG.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }

    /** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        /*
         * TODO: здесь необходимо свою верификацию реализовать Хорошо бы ещё с
         * использованием собственного стороннего сервера.
         */

        return true;
    }

    // Прокает, когда покупка завершена
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {


        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: "
                  + purchase);
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                return;
            }

            LOG.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_ADS_DISABLE)) {

                LOG.d(TAG, "Purchase for disabling ads done. Congratulating user.");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Purchase for disabling ads done.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // сохраняем в настройках, что отключили рекламу
                PreferencesHelper.savePurchase(context, PreferencesHelper.Purchase.DISABLE_ADS, true);
                // отключаем рекламу
                ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (ads != null)
            ads.onDestroy();

        if (mHelper != null)
            mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ads != null)
            ads.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (ads != null)
            ads.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (ads != null)
            ads.onStop();
    }
}
```

Хочу чтобы при нажатии но кнопку вылетал диалог с оплатой и когда отплатил, то больше не вылетал и реклама исчезала из приложения!

Вопрос вот в чем! как мне объявить об этой рекламе в коде(фрагменте)? никак не могу ее вытащить из активити...

// если отключили рекламу, то не будем показывать
    ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());

Comment: Кого вы пытаетесь вытащить из Активити и каким образом?

Comment: во фрагменте никак не могу ее объявить! вот тут: ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled()); что бы она работала!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос вот в чем! как мне объявить об этой рекламе в коде(фрагменте)?
>   никак не могу ее вытащить из активити...

```
   class MyActivity ...
   {
     ...
     public viud myMethod(...)
   }

  ((MyActivity)getActivity()).myMethod(...)
```

Comment: А можно как нить более полно ответить? Ато я новичок и не сильно понимаю что тут написано! Заранее благодарен...

Comment: Вам нужно просто сделать метод, убирающий рекламу, в самой активити. А из фрагмента дернуть его, взяв активити с помощью getActivity() и выполнив приведение типа - так как описано в ответе выше

Comment: отлично! спасибо! помогло! вот что значит объяснить и разложить по полочкам!